# Adding a div element class on hover onto an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am just trying to make the effect of an element appearing as the cursor hovers over an image. I want a box to appear where I can put content inside, possibly a video or an image. Here is what I have so far as the hover effects go and I tried writing a script to add the class but I'm not sure why it's not working.

```
<div id="scripture">
    <div class="hover11 column wholeimage">
        <div>
            <figure><img src="img/large.jpg" class="largeimage largerimage" /></figure>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(‘.column).hover(
            function(){$(this).toggleClass(hoveritem);}
        );

    </script>
```

CSS

```
.largerimager {
  opacity: 1
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -1000;

}

.wholeimage {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.hover11 figure img {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover11 figure:hover img {
    opacity: .75;
}

.largeimage {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.hoveritem {
    width: 200px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: what value does `hoveritem` have?

Comment: @madalinivascu That is the element I want to pop up when you hover over the image, like a black box on top of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in a document ready function, add simple quotes to the toggled class and the column selector

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
            $('.column').hover(
                function(){$(this).toggleClass('hoveritem');}
            );

    });
 </script>
```

better go with a mouseenter-mouseleave events

Answer (score 0):

`Quotes` are wrongly placed.And try with `$(document).ready(function(){}`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
$('.column').hover(
            function(){$(this).toggleClass('hoveritem');}
        );
  })
```

```css
.largerimager {
  opacity: 1
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -1000;

}

.wholeimage {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.hover11 figure img {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover11 figure:hover img {
    opacity: .75;
}

.largeimage {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.hoveritem {
    width: 200px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scripture">
    <div class="hover11 column wholeimage">
        <div>
            <figure><img src="img/large.jpg" class="largeimage largerimage" /></figure>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```